# Adding extra hydration to a CamelBak backpack

Tags: backpacks, hydration, hydration-bladders

I've had a CamelBak backpack for years (a Rim Runner that I bought in 2005), and for Christmas treated myself to a new [MilTac H.A.W.G.](https://www.camelbak.com/en/military/gmi-packs/M01005--MilTac_HAWG?color=bd80dd0d597a486395d6339327546e6e) as one of the zips on the old Rim Runner was starting to break and, well, I wanted something new.

I'm very pleased with the backpack, but one old issue persists; the 3l of water just isn't enough on 4+ hour hikes in hot weather (I'm in Australia, so it's summer here).

Has anyone had any success adding a second hydration reservoir to a pack? Is there typically space in the main reservoir pocket?

Comment: Even if there isn't enough space for a second bladder in the main reservoir pocket - what prevents you from carrying a second 3L bladder in the pack (and switching bladders when the first one is empty)? It looks like the pack is big enough for this.

Comment: Concerned about the bladder getting damaged by other things in the pack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the product, I don't quite comprehend why it would seem difficult to add a second reservoir, unless you aren't talking about a second hydration pack itself.

I think I trek around in similar conditions (India) as you do, and I typically face this issue, and for that I do the simplest thing I can think of.
Carry 3 bottles (1L each). When hydration bladder get empty, I refill it with water in the bottles. I plan to upgrade from hard bottles to collapsible water packs which I can place where I find enough volume for it to accommodate.

Comment: Of course the simplest options are often the best! I already had two 0.6l CamelBak [Podium Chill](http://camelbak.com.au/shop-by-sport/bike/podium-chill-6l-carbon/) (insulated!) bottles, which fit neatly in the main section of the backpack, either side of the "bump" caused by a full reservoir. These should give me enough extra water for most hikes I'm planning this summer.